# not passing sufficient arguments in the functions still the code is running

Tags: c++, function

```
void print(string str,int a=0)
{ 
 cout<<str;
}

int main()
{
string str="hello world";
print(str);
return 0;
}
```

why is the code working if I'am only passing one argument whereas the function needs two arguments

Comment: the second one is by default set to `0` in this moment `int a=0`, so you don't need to pass this argument during function call

Comment: [Default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a function with a defaulted argument

```
void some_func(int a, int def = 0)
{
    //something
}
```

The following call

```
some_func(42);
```

is converted into

```
some_func(42, 0);
```

And you can also call the function with two arguments, such as `some_func(42, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

It works because you defined this int on a function declaration. The compiler knows that a =0 and is an int type. However if you lets say call this function like this:

```
print(str,10);
```

int `a` will have value of 10 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring function with one argument to have a default initial value, that is why you are able to call function without that argument.

if not passing that argument to function, its initial value that you declared, is used.